# Glueing data of locally free sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So i want to know if there is a way to classify locally free sheaves via their glueing data.
Given a locally free sheaf, I know how you obtain the glueing data of it and that, if you glue along this datum you get the sheaf back you started with. Also i know that if you have a glueing datum say $ \phi_{ij}:(\mathcal{O}_{U_i\cap U_j })^n\rightarrow(\mathcal{O}_{U_j\cap U_i })^n $ you can can precompose it with isomorphisms of $ (\mathcal{O}_{U_i})^n $ or postcompose with
$ (\mathcal{O}_{U_j})^n $ and obtain the same sheaf. So it seems to me, that you have a bijection between glueing data mod the equivalence relation i described after passing to a cover that contains all intersections and locally free sheaves up to isomorphism. But what i know is not enough for that. You would need that given two isomorphic sheaves, you obtain "equivalent" glueing data. Is the bijection even true and if yes how would one show that? Thank you!

Comment: I think your equivalence relation is a bit too weak. If you have a sheaf $E$ with two different gluing data $(U_i^1, \phi_{ij}^1)$ and $(U_i^2, \phi_{ij}^2)$, you have to pass to a finer cover like $U_{i_1}^1 \cap U_{i_2}^2$ to compare them. Did you study how this is done for the case of line bundles, i.e. the Picard group? If not, learning this might be a first step.

Comment: i mean that is true, but as you said, one can just look at the intersections and get glueing data that are compareable.

Comment: For every single pair of gluing data, yes. But if you write down the set of all possible gluing data, then the equivalence relation has to take care of the intersections. Because for a single gluing datum, the open cover is fixed.

Comment: yeah i do get that. But the problem i have remains even after i redefine the equivalence relation to be essentially the thing i defined after passing to a finer cover. I'll edit that. But do you know how to prove that if you have two isomorphic sheaves you obtain equivalent glueing data?